# Integration not working

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can't seem to get this integration to work. s, n, b, b, l are all constants.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Sin[n Pi x / l] (1 + s x - Sqrt[(x - Sqrt[1 - b])^2 + b]), {x, 0,l}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

output is just the input, which indicates to me that mathematica doesn't like it, I'm unsure why.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a closed form solution? Not all integrals can be expressed in closed form.

Comment: From the form of your integral I guess you probably know more about the constants than you provide.  For example, if you add `Element[n, Integers]` and `l>0`to the Assumptions the constant term and the term linear in x evaluate no problem.  The problem is the square root piece.

Comment: "mathematica doesn't like it"---MA does not have the conscience therefore it cannot like or dislike something. Rather, integration cannot be performed analytically with the given assumptions.  Therefore, the input is returned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no known antiderivative for forms like $$\sqrt{1 -p x+ x^2} \sin (q x) ; q\neq 0$$

Comment: @yarchik What is this nonsense? Of course Mathematica has a conscience. And feelings. Which you have hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I have solution expressed **Only** by **Infinite Series**:
$\int_0^l \left(1+s x-\sqrt{b+\left(-\sqrt{1-b}+x\right)^2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi  x}{l}\right) \, dx=\\\frac{l (n \pi -n \pi  (1+l s) \cos (n \pi )+l s \sin (n \pi ))}{n^2 \pi
   ^2}+\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 l \sqrt{1-2 \sqrt{1-b} l+l^2} n^m (-\pi )^m F_1\left(1+m;-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};2+m;\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{-4+4 (1-b)}+2 \sqrt{1-b}\right)
   l,\frac{2 l}{\sqrt{-4+4 (1-b)}+2 \sqrt{1-b}}\right) \sin \left(\frac{m \pi }{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{-4+4 (1-b)} l-2 \sqrt{1-b} l} \sqrt{2+\sqrt{-4+4 (1-b)} l-2 \sqrt{1-b} l} (1+m)
   m!}$

```
f[b_, n_, l_, s_] := NIntegrate[Sin[n Pi x/l] (1 + s x - Sqrt[(x - Sqrt[1 - b])^2 + b]), {x, 0, l}];

f1[b_, n_, l_, s_, M_] := (l (n \[Pi] - n \[Pi] (1 + l s) Cos[n \[Pi]] + 
l s Sin[n \[Pi]]))/(n^2 \[Pi]^2) + Sum[(2 l Sqrt[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 - b] l + l^2] n^m (-\[Pi])^
 m AppellF1[1 + m, -(1/2), -(1/2), 2 + m, 1/2 (Sqrt[-4 + 4 (1 - b)] + 2 Sqrt[1 - b]) l, (2 l)/(
  Sqrt[-4 + 4 (1 - b)] + 2 Sqrt[1 - b])] Sin[(m \[Pi])/2])/(
 Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[-4 + 4 (1 - b)] l - 2 Sqrt[1 - b] l] Sqrt[
 2 + Sqrt[-4 + 4 (1 - b)] l - 2 Sqrt[1 - b] l] (1 + m) m!), {m, 0,M}] // N

 {f[1, 2, 3, 1], f1[1, 2, 3, 1, 30] // Chop} // MatrixForm

 (*{-0.298002, -0.298002}*)
```

**EDITED: 04.01.2024**

I use a Mellin Transform and Inverse Transformation:

```
A0 = Sin[n Pi x/l] (1 + s x - Sqrt[(x - Sqrt[1 - b])^2 + b]) // 
Factor // Expand (*I use only last term*)
A = FullSimplify[MellinTransform[-A0 // Last, n, s] /. b -> 1/4 (4 - a^2),a > 0]
B = Integrate[A, {x, 0, l}, Assumptions -> l > 0 && s > 0]
B1 = InverseMellinTransform[B[[1]], s, n](* Can't compute. No wonder he can't find the answer. *)
Inactivate[Sum[Assuming[m \[Element] Integers && m >= 0, 
Residue[(B[[1]] /. a -> 2*Sqrt[1 - b])*n^(-s), {s, -m}]], {m, 0, Infinity}], Sum]
```

Comment: There are no words to describe how impressed I am. Out of curiosity and for educational purposes, could you please elaborate on how derived it? Whenever you have some time.

Comment: @bmf. I update the answer.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set constants values for your Constants so the integral can be evaluated. Otherwise it return error for solution to set constant values.

```
n = 1;
s = 1;
l = 1;
b = 1;

f[x_] := Refine[
  Sin[n Pi x/l] *(1 + s x - Sqrt[(x - Sqrt[1 - b])^2 + b]), 
  Assumptions -> {Element[x, Reals]}
  ]




Integrate[Simplify[f[x]], {x, 0, 1}] // N
```